Determine a function and calculate the area of the triangle formed by the geometric image of the graph with the coordinate axes.
the problem
a) Determine the function $f:R->R, f(x)=ax+b$ knowing that $a$ and $b$ are rational numbers and $f(1+\sqrt5)=5+3 \sqrt{5}$.
b) Graphically represent the function determined at point a) and calculate the area of the triangle formed by the geometric image of the graph with the coordinate axes.
my idea
I was able to do the first point and half of the second...
a) $f(1+\sqrt{5})=a+a\sqrt{5}+b=5+3\sqrt5$
$a\sqrt5-3\sqrt5=\sqrt5(a-3)=5-a-b$
Because $\sqrt5(a-3)$ is irrational if $a-3$ isn't 0 and $5-a-b$ is rational, so $a-3=0=> a=3$ and $5-a-b=5-3-b=2-b=0=> b=2$
So we determined the function $f(x)=3x+2$
For point be I represented the graphic taking the points A(0,2) and B(-1,-1) which belong to $G_f$

For the rest I don't understand how I should interest the geometric image of the graph with the coordinate axes
All I know is that the image of $G_f$ is ${f(x)\in R| x\in R}$
Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Let’s find the root of $f$: $$3x+2=0$$ $$x=-\frac23$$
Now the sides of the right triangle are $2$ and $\frac23$, so its area is $$\frac12\cdot\frac23\cdot2=\frac23.$$

Oooo... so the geometric image of the graph is actually the graph???

@IONELABUCIU The graph of a function is a set ${(x,f(x)):x\in \mathbb R}$. The geometric image of it is a straight line.

@IONELABUCIU See the first paragraph in Wikipedia, for example.
